# My google script is slowing down my spreadsheet very badly

Tags: performance, google-sheets, protocols, slowdown

I'm a total beginner when it comes to writing scripts but somehow managed to copy-paste/write this script that protocols the date when a specific cell has been updated. Somehow the script slows down my spreadsheet so badly that I have to wait a few seconds for every change I make. I used the `s.getRange()` function instead of `s.getActiveCell()` because in some cases I want to change up to 30 cells at once and it should then protocol all the changes. Could this maybe slowdown my sheet? Or does anyone have other ideas how I can speed up my sheet?

Why I entered the following functions:

`(r.getRow() !1 & r.getRow() !=2)` so that the 2 title rows can be change without being protocoled

`var name1versandstatus = s.getRange("datum1versandspalte")` so that I can insert new columns without affecting the scripts function

```
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Strukturierung" ) { 
   var r = s.getActiveRange(); // 

   if ( r.getRow() !=1 & r.getRow() !=2) {     
   var name1versandstatus = s.getRange("datum1versandspalte") 

   if( r.getColumn() == name1versandstatus.getColumn()) { 

     if(r.getValue() == "Versendet"){
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1); 
       nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Google Spreadsheet is online and calculations are done on the server side which makes everything a bit slower but it's usually good at handling a queue of incoming changes.

Comment: I don't understand this line `var name1versandstatus = s.getRange("datum1versandspalte")`. I don't see any getRange that's designed to use a string except for A1Notation.

Comment: @Cooper getRangeByName exists, I'm not sure if getRange also handles named ranges.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I think it's a spreadsheet command